# Citrix workspace Ubuntu would not connect

Tags: citrix

After trying to login to virtual PC, it downloads the ica file. 
Running the file with the workspace client gives the following error:

```
You have not chosen to trust "DigiCert Global Root G2"
```

There are some discussions for Mac, but none for Linux.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, I solved it this way for Ubuntu 20.04:

1. Download the DigiCert Global Root G2 certificate from Digicert's site https://www.digicert.com/digicert-root-certificates.htm. The exact link for this certificate on this page is https://cacerts.digicert.com/DigiCertGlobalRootG2.crt
2. Copy the downloaded certificate file to the folder /opt/Citrix/ICAClient/keystore/cacerts

```
sudo cp DigiCertGlobalRootG2.crt /opt/Citrix/ICAClient/keystore/cacerts
```

Now you shouldn't see this error. Basically Citrix maintains its own cert store which is different from the browser's cert store, hence the cert file needs to copied to Citrix's folder also.

I adapted the solution from the site: https://newspaint.wordpress.com/2015/10/05/linux-citrix-receiver-ssl-error-addtrust-external-ca-root/

Answer (score 0):

I solved this for Ubuntu 18.04:

1. Downloaded the certificate (PEM) from the browser view (Citrix light version)
2. Copied the certificate to $ICAROOT/keystore/cacerts
3. Ran the $ICAROOT/util/ctx_rehash as sudo

Reference - https://support.citrix.com/article/CTX231524